# <h:Link> tag: How can the value attribute have an Image instead of text?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I have a  tag with which i return to the home page.

```
<h:link  value="Home" outcome="/webpages/NewWelcome.xhtml"/>
```

I would like to have an png Home icon instead of "Home" text. 
How can I add an image into the value attribute.

**I tried**

```
<h:link  value="#{<img style="border:0;" src="smiley.gif" alt="HTML tutorial" width="42" height="42">}" outcome="/webpages/NewWelcome.xhtml" />
```

This obviously **didn't work**. I am not sure how can i.

Any Help would be appreciated.
Thank You :)

Comment: Didn't you try adding image as a child component of h:link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `h:graphicImage` inside `h:link`:

```
<h:link outcome="home" >
    <h:graphicImage value="/images/home.png" style="border: none" />
</h:link>
```

Comment: If you aren't sure, why don't you try it yourself before posting an answer? Then you can just tell from own experience and you don't need to post such a hesitating answer with "Try this" without any valuable technical elaboration.

Comment: @BalusC Posted code is in working condition - code was tested. This simple code doesn't need additional explanation.

Comment: Why then the hesitating "Try this" statement?

Comment: @BalusC Text is changed

Comment: thank you folks for the help :) it was quite obvious, shame it didnt click to me! this is just the same as simple html tags widout jsf tags.
It is working perfectly! :)

Comment: and if we want to use bootstrap icon?